# Accessing Azure Storage through keys managed by Azure Key Vault via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-keyvault

I am having trouble accessing my storage account keys in a managed key vault.
Here is my code:

```
$secret = Get-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $storageAccountName
$ctx =New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $secret.SecretValueText
```

It seems that $secret.SecretValueText is empty/null. How do I retrieve the storage account key correctly? This is the error that appears.

```
New-AzStorageContext : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'StorageAccountKey'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

Comment: If you're trying to get a secret, shouldn't you be using `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret`? Does `$secret` have a SecretValueText property in your code?

Comment: Please refer to https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/38015650-support-pulling-storage-account-key-from-azure-key. It seems that we cannot do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely it will be empty, the [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultmanagedstorageaccount?view=azps-4.6.1#outputs) of `Get-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount` is [`PSKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.keyvault.models.pskeyvaultmanagedstorageaccount?view=azurerm-ps), it does not have such a property, the `SecretValueText` is a property of [`PSKeyVaultSecret`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.keyvault.models.pskeyvaultsecret?view=azurerm-ps).

And I don't think you can get the storage account key via `Get-AzKeyVaultManagedStorageAccount`, if you want to get the storage account key, you can use the command below, make sure your logged user account/service principal has the RBAC role e.g. `Storage Account Key Operator Service Role`, `Contributor`, `Owner` in your storage account.

```
$key = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name <storageaccount-name>).Value[0]
New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName <storageaccount-name> -StorageAccountKey $key
```

[image]